# Changes allowed in react-native code-push

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

I have added react-native-code-push in my react native app and if I add a new page in my page and then deploy it on code-push cloud, it will work or not?

What is the limit of changing the things in react-native-code-push?

Please do tell that what if I deployed in code push cloud and app store both, then the users will get the update button in play store or not?

Can we push the changes only to some users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using CodePush in production for quite sometime now.

> I have added react-native-code-push in my react native app and if I
>   add a new page in my page and then deploy it on code-push cloud, it
>   will work or not?

It will work smooth!

> What is the limit of changing the things in react-native-code-push?

Any JS change can be pushed via CodePush.

> Please do tell that what if I deployed in code push cloud and app
>   store both, then the users will get the update button in play store or
>   not?

Only if you have any changes that have changed your native code. (Ex- Add a library that has a native module linked) You need to make sure you deploy via Playstore/Appstore.